# Inequalities with a function that has a removable discontinuity

Tags: inequality

$$ f(x)= \frac{x^2}{x(x+1)} $$

I understand that this function has a removable discontinuity at $ x=0 $.

$$ \frac{x^2}{x(x+1)} \le 0 $$

But according to Desmos, the answer to this inequality is $ (-∞,-1)\cup[0,∞) $.

I understand that $\lim_{x\to0} f(x) = 0$, but still, the function is undefined at $x=0$. So, I don't get why the $0$ is included.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't give some feature of Desmos—whose code is not even open source, to my knowledge—precedence over your (correct) mathematical understanding of the inequality.

Comment: But, also, [Desmos seems to get this correct](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kku2z7fhqi).

Answer (score 1):

Probably, Desmos provides the answer corresponding to the proposed expression after it is simplified.

Indeed, we obtain the following collection of systems in such case:
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{x + 1} \geq 0 & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x\geq 0\\\\
x + 1 > 0
\end{cases}\ \text{or} \
\begin{cases}
x\leq 0\\\\
x + 1 < 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
which yields the claimed result.